# Sed - Replacing text string containing parentheses, commas and unspecified number of whitespaces

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, replace

Assume an alphanumeric text string that contains a section comprising a keyword, parentheses, and commas as well as a line break and an unspecified number of whitespaces immediately following some or all of the commas. How do I replace such a section from the text string with a simple comma in `bash` (preferentially using `sed`)?

Example:

```
$ cat have.txt
foo (keyword(00001..00002),keyword(00003..00004),
   keyword(00005..00006),keyword(00007..00008)) foo 
$ cat want.txt 
foo (keyword(00001..00002,00003..00004,00005..00006,00007..00008)) foo
```

Attempt:

```
$ sed 's/),keyword(/,/g' have.txt
foo (keyword(00001..00002,00003..00004),
   keyword(00005..00006,00007..00008)) foo
```

(And, yes, I know that whitespaces can be captured via `[[:space:]]`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -z 's/),\s*keyword(/,/g' file
```

With `-z`,  you will be able to match linebreaks, the `\s*` will match zero or more whitespace including those linebreaks.

To actually modify the file use

```
sed -z -i 's/),\s*keyword(/,/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat >> edrep.txt << EOF

2s/   //
%s/(//g
%s/)//g
%s/keyword//g
1s/00001/\(keyword\(00001/
2s/8/8))/
1,2j
wq
EOF

ed -s file.txt < edrep.txt
```

I know this one has already been answered, but I felt like posting this solution anyway.  People here will probably consider it hackish; but the point is that you can climb around text files like a monkey with ed, and I don't know of any other program which lets you do that to the same degree.